# Standard lib or Akka for Scala.2.10.1?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

I am going to use `Futures` and `Promises` from `scala.concurrent` package in Scala **2.10.1**. Should I use `Akka` instead ?

Comment: Recent Akka versions use Scala's (Sip-14) Futures [in their docs on the regular basis](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html), so I guess you would be better to use Scala ones.

Comment: Right - the recent versions don't even have `Future` anymore.

Comment: Hey gents - I just left an answer explaining this - they're synonymous - use the scala ones as they ARE the akka ones.

Comment: Actually there are differences between Akka 2.0 Futures and SIP-14 futures.  But they are mostly the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Akka futures and promises were moved into Scala standard library in 2.10 so there is no difference. It's not that you're using the standard scala classes - the old scala classes no longer exist and have been replaced by akka's.

Use akka actors as scala ones are deprecated in scala 2.11

See akka 2.0 to 2.1 migration for details of what is in the standard scala library now. 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html

```
Search  Replace with
akka.dispatch.Await scala.concurrent.Await
akka.dispatch.Future    scala.concurrent.Future
akka.dispatch.Promise   scala.concurrent.Promise
akka.dispatch.ExecutionContext  scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
akka.util.Duration  scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
akka.util.duration  scala.concurrent.duration
akka.util.Deadline  scala.concurrent.duration.Deadline
akka.util.NonFatal  scala.util.control.NonFatal
akka.japi.Util.manifest akka.japi.Util.classTag
```

Comment: Thank you. BTW, should I still use actors of Akka i/o Scala actors ?

Comment: Use the akka ones - in scala 2.11 scala actors are being deprecated. Updated my answer. PS akka rocks!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks a bit inconsistent to use `scala.concurrent` for one API (`Futures/Promises`) and `akka` for another though.

Comment: Look at the akka documentation and you'll see it's the same there. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html

Comment: Fyi - the advice here holds true:
in scala 2.10.2 scala actors are officially deprecated and the akka actors now come bundled with scala.
http://www.scala-lang.org/2.10.2-RC2