# Futures in Scala and Akka

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future

How is Scala Futures different from Akka Futures, is one of them better than the other? Conceptually they seem similar, making non-blocking, asynchronous programming easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard lib or Akka for Scala.2.10.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508200/standard-lib-or-akka-for-scala-2-10-1)

Answer (score 3):

Since version *2.10*, the scala standard library integrated most versions of `Futures` coming from differing libraries (akka, twitter, dispatch, ...) to create a default implementation [based on akka's version].

The latest *Akka* libraries (from 2.1 IIRC) directly use the aforementioned implementation from the 2.10 standard lib, so you don't have to choose if you're on the current delivery train.

We could say that "Scala and Akka futures are now merged" ... in many ways

Comment: In one way this is accurate, in another way you have it upside down.

Comment: Yep, you're right, the scala 2.10 version is actually akka's. I was trying to convey the process that lead to integrating all those future implementations within a shared API. Actually I like your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

The Future you see in scala are very inspired from Twitter's Future library and Akka's Future library. In fact it is the best from the both with minute tweaks here and there. (There is post explaining all this but I am unable to find the link to it :( )

The akka documentation is now modified to use Scala SDK future rather than its own. I hope this answers.

Answer (score 1):

Akka actors are the default actor library for Scala 2.10 and the *scala.actors* library has been deprecated in Scala 2.11; people are advised to use the *akka.actors* library and there is an [Actors Migration guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html) for people already using native Scala actors already. So use the Akka actors because the native Scala version isn't going to get any more love.

On the other hand, because Akka actors are becoming the default in Scala, Scala's various concurrency libraries have been updated to work with Akka actors.  This means that on the Akka side, a whole bunch of alternative libraries they provided are no longer necessary.  This is explained in their Akka 2.0 to 2.1 [migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html)